# background color of parent matching height of child with negative top and bottom margins

Tags: html, css, margin

Attached is an image of the desired affect I am going for. I am trying to do this with negative margins. I need the child element to expand past the parent element on the top and bottom. The issue is the background color of the parent element is matching the height of the child element. This is a responsive site and I will not be able to use absolute positioning of the child element as the height of the child (and therefore parent element) will be variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Following is my code...

```css
body {
  background-color:#DBD9DB;
}

#headerImage {
  margin: 0;
}

#headerImage img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#parent {
 background-color: #fff4d7;
}

#child {
 background:none #FFF;
 margin:-46px auto -38px;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
 width:80%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="headerImage">
    <img src="http://fpoimg.com/300x250?text=Preview" width="300" height="250" />
  </div>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus sapien a nulla finibus mattis id quis est. Proin malesuada magna vitae orci maximus, ac viverra felis iaculis. Curabitur lacinia commodo est et auctor. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla scelerisque metus et leo cursus, non auctor turpis fermentum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: #DBD9DB;
}


#parent {
  background-color: #fff4d7;
}

#parent:before,
#parent:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#child {
  background: none #FFF;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: -50px auto;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}


img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent clearfix">
    <div class="css-slideshow">
          <div id="parent">
                        <img class="clearfix" src="http://unilaboralgirona.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ZContact.jpg" />
      <div id="child">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus sapien a nulla finibus mattis id quis est. Proin malesuada magna vitae orci maximus, ac viverra felis iaculis. Curabitur lacinia commodo est et auctor. Suspendisse potenti.
          Nulla scelerisque metus et leo cursus, non auctor turpis fermentum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately i can't absolutely position the header image as it too will be responsive; so its, and its parent wrapper's height will be variable.

Comment: @masterShake no idea what you need, I added an img for my code

Comment: your adjusted solution is exactly what i was looking for. thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements in the `#parent` **id** to change the `background-color` and then use negative margin in `#child`.

Check this snippet out:

```css
body {
    background-color:#DBD9DB;
}

#headerImage {
    margin: 0;
}

#headerImage img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#parent {
    background-color: #fff4d7;

}
#parent:before, #parent:after{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#child {
    background:none #FFF;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    width:80%;
    margin: -50px auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="headerImage">
    <img src="http://fpoimg.com/300x250?text=Preview" width="300" height="250" />
  </div>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus sapien a nulla finibus mattis id quis est. Proin malesuada magna vitae orci maximus, ac viverra felis iaculis. Curabitur lacinia commodo est et auctor. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla scelerisque metus et leo cursus, non auctor turpis fermentum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! That will definitely work for the bottom. But up top I need the child to appear to lay on top of the image.